# Removing elements in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to parse here. Here is the content of my array

```
Array ( [61] => [128] => [158] => [224] => [281] => AGAS, [282] => JAMES [283] => JAY [285] => [329] => [330] => 03/02/2015 [331] => 6:46 [332] => am [333] => 5:42 [334] => pm [433] => APOLLOL, [434] => KARMIN [436] => [480] => [481] => 03/01/2015 [598] => )
```

As I can see there are null values in my array, I have tried this code:

```
$final2=array_filter($final);
$trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$final2);
```

But some of the null values are not remove and also how can I make my array like these:

```
Array ([1] => AGAS, [2] => JAMES [3] => JAY [4] => [5] => 03/02/2015 [6] => 6:46 [7] => am [8] => 5:42 [9] => pm [10] => APOLLOL, [11] => KARMIN [12] => 03/01/2015)
```

Comment: Can you install the `xdebug` extension and produce the var_dumps again? It will show datatypes and put `""` around strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to below given function. Hope this will help you. This function will convert all null values to blank("").

```
function array_remove_empty($Yourarray) {
        foreach ($Yourarray as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $Yourarray[$key] = array_remove_empty($Yourarray[$key]);
            }

            if (empty($Yourarray[$key])) {
                $Yourarray[$key] = "";
            }
        }

        return $Yourarray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
$inputArray = array (
'61'=> '',
'128' => '',
'158' => '',
'224' => '',
'281' => 'AGAS',
'282' => 'JAMES' ,
'283' => 'JAY' ,
'285' =>'',
'329' => '',
'330' =>  '03/02/2015',
'331' => '6:46' ,
'332' => 'am' ,
'333' => '5:42',
'334' =>'pm' ,
'433' => 'APOLLOL',
'434' =>'KARMIN' ,
'436' =>'' ,
'480' => '',
'481' => '03/01/2015' ,
'598' => '',
);
```

---

```
$reqResult = array (
'1' => 'AGAS',
'2' => 'JAMES',
'3' => 'JAY',
'4' =>'',
'5' => '03/02/2015',
'6' => '6:46',
'7' => 'am' ,
'8' => '5:42' ,
'9' => 'pm' ,
'10' => 'APOLLOL',
'11'=> 'KARMIN' ,
'12' => '03/01/2015',
);
```

---

Im assuming offset 4 in reqResult was a mistake.

```
$myResult = array();
$i=1;
foreach($inputArray as $key => $value){
if($value!=''){
    $myResult[$i]= $value;
    $i++;
    }
}
print_r($myResult);
```